# How to fix topmost row and leftmost column of a calendar-like layout while keeping their contents scrollable?

Tags: flutter

**Problem Overview**

I'm trying to make the topmost row and leftmost column of the layout illustrated in the below blueprint image fixed but at the same time I want their contents to be scrollable with the grid area of the tasks based on the scrolling direction of the screen.

[image]

**Expected Result**

1. Action area: This should be fixed in position (top & left) while scrolling both vertically and horizontally
2. Topmost Row: This should be fixed to the top while scrolling vertically but scrolls horizontally while scrolling the screen horizontally
3. Leftmost Column: This should be fixed to the left while scrolling horizontally but scrolls vertically while scrolling the screen vertically

**Actual Behaviour**

Currently I managed to get the fixing part and vertical scrolling part of the leftmost column right but I can't figure out  how to make the topmost row scrolls HORIZONTALLY as the user scrolls the screen horizontally please see the GIF

[image]

**Code Snippet**

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 56,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          // Action Button
          TextButton(),

          // Topmost Row
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: days.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 64) / 3,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          days[index]['dayName'],
                        ),
                        Text(
                          days[index]['day'],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: workingHours.length * 161,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 64,
                  child: Column(
                    children: List.generate(
                      workingHours.length,
                      (i) => Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            // Hours
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: days.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width:
                                (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 64) /
                                    3,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                // Tasks
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```